# Accessing context provider, that has a useEffect hook, at nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am triggering a useEffect hook that loads some data in my ContextProvider, like this...

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const ResultsContext = createContext({
  currResultsTab: "",
  changeCurrResultsTab: () => {},
  data: {},
  currOpt: "",
  processed: false,
  loading:true
});

export const ResultsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currResultsTab, setCurrResultsTab] = useState("IRR");
  const [data, setData] = useState({})
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  const changeCurrResultsTab = (e, v) => v && setCurrResultsTab(v);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadData = async () =>{
       const data = await getStuff()
       setData(data)
    }
    loadData()
    setLoading(false)
  }, []);

  const resultsContextValue = {
    currResultsTab: currResultsTab,
    changeCurrResultsTab: changeCurrResultsTab,
    data:data,
    currOpt: "",
    loading:loading
  };
  return (
    <ResultsContext.Provider value={resultsContextValue}>
      {children}
    </ResultsContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and I am accessing it in a child nested component like this...

**NOTE**: The following is already wrapped in 'ResultsContextProvider/>' in its parent

```
import {ResultsContext}  from '../store/resultsContext';

export default memo(function ResultsTab({
  currOpt,
  processed
}) {
  console.log("RENDER RESULTS TAB")

  const resultsContext = useContext(ResultsContext)
    currResultsTab, 
    changeCurrResultsTab,
    data,
    loading
  } = resultsContext
  console.log(resultsContext)
  console.log(data)

return (
   <div className='row mx-auto align-items-center'>
     <BasicToggle
       currOption={currResultsTab}
       options={['IRR', 'Credit', 'RBC']}
       onChange={changeCurrResultsTab}
       />
    <div>
    {map and show data}
    </div>
   </div>
)
})
```

My issue is that when destructure resultsContext in the child, data is an empty bracket.

But when i console.log(resultsContext) I can see that data is in fact not empty.

When I change the tab (and thus force ResultsTab child component to re-render), the data object is no longer empty.

Why is my data object empty initially? And how can I fix this?

Thanks,
Logan

Comment: It’s empty because the useEffect only runs after your component has mounted and done its initial render. Use the `loading` flag as an indicator to know whether you have the data or not.

Comment: I understand this, but this is not the case. Even after loading is false (done loading), the destructured data object is still empty. If i change tabs and force state to re-rener,  the data object is then populated. 

resultsContext.data is empty until I force a component reevaluation via tab change. But Loading is successfully updated, so strange

Comment: The issue was with my useEffect, it was more complicated than displayed in the example. setting state multiple times for one object upon getting more data with doing a functional update. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

This example actually works well, the issue was with the useEffect in my context provider not doing a functional state update.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).